# Inserting Text into tables of a power point slide using PPTX package adds a carriage return before desired text

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am using the Python PPTX package to generate tables into a powerpoint presentation.  I have a template which is loaded then I generate two tables on the first slide.

Tables are 5,2 each with the first row merged, in the merged row of each table I am attemping to enter text.  I can get the text to insert, however, my code seems to add a carriage return before the text, them the top row ends up a different height to the rest of the rows.

My code below

```
    from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor
    from pptx.util import Cm
    from pptx.util import Pt
    
    from pptx.enum.text import PP_ALIGN
    from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor

    prs = Presentation('pathto/Template.pptx')

    # Select the second slide (index 1 since slide indexes start from 0)
    slide = prs.slides[1]
    
    # Define the position and size of the first table
    x1, y1, cx1, cy1 = Cm(4), Cm(4), Cm(8), Cm(6)
    
    # Add the first table shape to the slide
    shape1 = slide.shapes.add_table(5, 2, x1, y1, cx1, cy1)
    
    # Access the first table object
    table1 = shape1.table
    
    # Merge cells in the top row of the first table
    table1.cell(0, 0).merge(table1.cell(0, 1))
    
    # Get the merged cell in the first table
    merged_cell1 = table1.cell(0, 0)
    
    # Set text and formatting for the merged cell in the first table
    text_frame1 = merged_cell1.text_frame
    text_frame1.clear()  # Clear existing text
    p1 = text_frame1.add_paragraph()
    p1.text = "Background Window"
    p1.alignment = PP_ALIGN.CENTER
    p1.font.name = "Calibri Light"
    p1.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0, 0, 0)  # Black font color
    p1.font.size = Pt(14)  # Change the font size to the desired value
    
    # Define the position and size of the second table
    x2, y2, cx2, cy2 = Cm(4), Cm(11), Cm(8), Cm(6)
    
    # Add the second table shape to the slide
    shape2 = slide.shapes.add_table(5, 2, x2, y2, cx2, cy2)
    
    # Access the second table object
    table2 = shape2.table
    
    # Merge cells in the top row of the second table
    table2.cell(0, 0).merge(table2.cell(0, 1))
    
    # Get the merged cell in the second table
    merged_cell2 = table2.cell(0, 0)
    
    # Set text and formatting for the merged cell in the second table
    text_frame2 = merged_cell2.text_frame
    text_frame2.clear()  # Clear existing text
    p2 = text_frame2.add_paragraph()
    p2.text = "Activity Tracker"
    p2.alignment = PP_ALIGN.CENTER
    p2.font.name = "Calibri Light"
    p2.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0, 0, 0)  # Black font color
    p2.font.size = Pt(14)  # Change the font size to the desired value
```

How do I stop the carriage return from being inserted?  I am going to start populating the rest of the tables with additional information so would like to prevent it from occurring there for the remainder of the table as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I am using add.Paragraph where I needed reference the cell with .text = "mytext"

```
    # Select the second slide (index 1 since slide indexes start from 0)
    slide = prs.slides[1]
    
    # Define the position and size of the first table
    x1, y1, cx1, cy1 = Cm(4), Cm(4), Cm(8), Cm(6)
    
    # Add the first table shape to the slide
    shape1 = slide.shapes.add_table(5, 2, x1, y1, cx1, cy1)
    
    # Access the first table object
    table1 = shape1.table
    
    # Merge cells in the top row of the first table
    table1.cell(0, 0).merge(table1.cell(0, 1))
    
    # Get the merged cell in the first table
    merged_cell1 = table1.cell(0, 0)
    
    # Set text and formatting for the merged cell in the first table
    text_frame1 = merged_cell1.text_frame
    text_frame1.clear()  # Clear existing text
    merged_cell1.text = "Background Window"
    merged_cell1.alignment = PP_ALIGN.CENTER
    merged_cell1.font.name = "Calibri Light"
    merged_cell1.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0, 0, 0)  # Black font color
    merged_cell1.font.size = Pt(14)  # Change the font size to the desired value
    
    # Define the position and size of the second table
    x2, y2, cx2, cy2 = Cm(4), Cm(11), Cm(8), Cm(6)
    
    # Add the second table shape to the slide
    shape2 = slide.shapes.add_table(5, 2, x2, y2, cx2, cy2)
    
    # Access the second table object
    table2 = shape2.table
    
    # Merge cells in the top row of the second table
    table2.cell(0, 0).merge(table2.cell(0, 1))
    
    # Get the merged cell in the second table
    merged_cell2 = table2.cell(0, 0)
    
    # Set text and formatting for the merged cell in the second table
    text_frame2 = merged_cell2.text_frame
    text_frame2.clear()  # Clear existing text
    
    merged_cell2.text = "Activity Tracker"
    merged_cell2.alignment = PP_ALIGN.CENTER
    merged_cell2.font.name = "Calibri Light"
    merged_cell2.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0, 0, 0)  # Black font color
    merged_cell2.font.size = Pt(14)  # Change the font size to the desired value
```